# Generate random matrices $L$ and $D$ such that $LL^T + D$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices

How do I generate random matrices $L$ and $D$ such that $LL^T + D$ is positive definite. I need to apply stochastic variational inference and I want to initialise my parameters $L$ and $D$ randomly such that the matrix $LL^T + D$ is always positive definite and then apply Cholesky decomposition on it. How do I achieve this?

I understood that randomly initialising my matrices is not a good idea and there needs to be some pattern. Any help would be great!

Edit: Yes $D$ is a diagonal matrix

Comment: it's enough that $D$ is diagonal with positive elements

Comment: @Exodd what about $L$? Can i do it randomly?

Comment: as long as it's real, yes

Comment: @thedumbkid To clarify, for any diagonal matrix $D$ with positive diagonal elements and any matrix $L$ with real entries (such that $LL^T$ has the same shape as $D$), $LL^T + D$ will be positive definite. Does that answer your question? If not, please clarify what you're still trying to figure out.